# After Effects Bodymovin plugin render button disabled

Tags: after-effects, plugins

When I try to use bodymovin to convert my animation in After Effects my render button is disabled (gray instead of green and nothing happens if I click on it). Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must indicate the destination folder in order for the button to be enabled. Once you select the composition you want to render out, to the right side of the composition name in the plugin window, just click on the three dots icon and choose a destination. The render button should then be clickable.